# Java 7 on a V-Server: "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Tags: debian, java, linux-vserver

I've just installed Java 7 & Jenkins on a V-Server with 1Gb of RAM

```
# java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

And Ram

```
#free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1548       1506         41          0          0       1096
-/+ buffers/cache:        409       1138
Swap:          200         24        175
```

Jenkins alocating

```
#top | grep jenkins
 7837 jenkins   20   0 16676  544  372 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 daemon
 7841 jenkins   20   0  791m 298m  18m S    0 19.3   1:31.52 java
```

Is there a way to tell the whole java VM to use at least 1GB of Ram? How can I configure the start params of jenkins eq ram max 512.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try running this and see what happens:

java -Xmx256m -version

Comment: Its Working (**java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
**)

Comment: Interesting, it may be setting the default min/max the same and looks like the VM doesn't have enough free space.  If your machine is 1GB the Xmx should probably be set to 768m.